# iOS 15.3 has broken SwiftUI layout

Tags: swiftui

I just upgraded my phone from 15.x (I think 15.2) to 15.3, and my SwiftUI layout is broken, seems to be a List border issue.

Here is the code, followed by a screen shot of normal behavior (13.x to 15.x) and then what I see in 15.3

```
struct SessionView: View {
    var title: String
    var panel: Int
    var index: Int
    var range: [Int] = [0,2,3,4]
    
    @EnvironmentObject var state: MainViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var content: ContentViewModel

    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            // -- Header
            HStack() {
                Text(" ")
                Image(self.state.panelIcon(panel: panel)).resizable().frame(width: 12.0, height: 12.0)
                Text(title)
                Spacer()
            }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 0, bottom: 8, trailing: 0))
            .background(Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9))
            .onTapGesture {
                showDetailDialog()
            }

            // -- Rows
            List {
                ForEach(0..<5) { i in
                    if i != 1 { // Skip IP address
                        HStack(alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, spacing: -4, content: {
                            Text("\(state.keyValues[i+index]!.key)").frame(minWidth: 120, maxHeight: 20, alignment: .leading)
                                .font(Font.system(size: 15, design: .default)).padding(0)
                            Text("\(state.keyValues[i+index]!.value)").frame(maxHeight: 20, alignment: .leading)
                                .font(Font.system(size: 15, design: .default)).padding(0)
                        }).frame(height: 10)
                    }
                }
            }.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 10)
            .frame(height: 4*20+20)
            .listStyle(DefaultListStyle()).environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 8).onAppear {
                UITableView.appearance().isScrollEnabled = false
            }.layoutPriority(1)
        }.overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(Color(red: 0.8, green: 0.8, blue: 0.8), lineWidth: 1.25)
        ).background(Color.white)
        
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too. However, it is not a border issue. When you updated your iPhone, the default list style for SwiftUI changed. The old default style is now called *PlainListStyle()*. Use that instead to get the old look back.

```
List {
    
}.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```